# Avoid repeating "!.gitignore" in every .gitignore of my sub-folders?

Tags: git, gitignore

Each subfolder of `src/` has a `.gitignore` in it:

```
.
├── chartbrew
│   ├── compose.yaml
│   ├── .env
│   ├── .gitignore
│   └── README.md
├── directus
│   ├── compose.yaml
│   ├── .env
│   ├── extensions
│   ├── .gitignore
│   ├── README.md
│   └── uploads
├── lcmp
│   ├── compose.yaml
│   ├── .env
│   ├── .gitignore
│   ├── public
│   └── README.md
├── metabase
│   ├── compose.yaml
│   ├── .env
│   ├── .gitignore
│   └── README.md
└── uptime-kuma
    ├── compose.yaml
    ├── .env
    ├── .gitignore
    └── README.md
```

In each **sub-folder `.gitignore`** has, at least (content may vary):

```
*
!compose.yaml
!README.md
```

So far so good, *but for every sub-folder `.gitignore` in it is excluded from git*. To solve this, I added a **root `.gitignore`** without success:

```
!src/*/.gitignore
```

(I can put `!.gitignore` in every sub-folder's `.gitignore`, but I want to avoid this repetition)

Comment: I don't think there is a way. Once you ignore everything with `*` in a `.gitignore` you overrode all exclusions from all higher-level `.gitignore`. May be you want to move common parts of `.gitignore`s to the top-level one?

Comment: @phd I see. What I dont' know it's why "*" doesn't ignore all files relative to the subdirectoy. It's something I can't get, because AFAIK paths are relative to where .gitignore is placed...

Comment: "*…paths are relative to where .gitignore is placed.*" Yes, exactly. "*…why `*` doesn't ignore all files relative to the subdirectoy…*" What do you mean? It surely ignores everything related to the directory of `.gitignore`. What doesn't it ignore for you?

Comment: I hope you know [`git check-ignore`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-check-ignore)? `git check-ignore -v <files>`

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstood, I was just confused. Indeed it ignores all files and directory relative to where is placed. What I was missing is the root .gitignore, not having an "higher" precedence.

Comment: If you want to ignore everything and you have just a few exceptions, it is probably much easier to have a top-level `.gitignore` with just `*`, and then you `git add -f` the files that you do *not* want to ignore. No additional `.gitignore` files are needed.

Answer (score 0):

If you have only 1 level of subdirectories, the following should work:

```
# .gitignore at root level:

*/*
!*/README.md
!*/compose.yaml
!*/.gitignore
```

You can then add custom ignore rules in each individual `.gitignore` file.